# How can I not take in consideration values join without record on the db

Tags: mysql

I'm in front of a "minor" problem taht looks easy but I didn't suceed to resolve it.

I have three tables in my Database :

Table gp

```
____________
id | name | 
____________
1 | Le Mans|     
2 | Toulon |    
3 | Rennes |
```

Table player

```
____________
id | name | 
____________
1 | Thibaut|     
2 | Fred |    
3 | Samir |
```

Table Records

```
_____________________________
id | gp_id | player_id | time  
_____________________________
1 | 1 | 1 | 17860    
2 | 2 | 1 | 11311
3 | 3 | 1 | 33133
4 | 3 | 2 | 11113
5 | 2 | 2 | 44444  
6 | 1 | 2 | 13131
7 | 1 | 3 | 11111
8 | 3 | 3 | 21112
```

I want to get a sum of time for players that have a record on every gp ( so in my case, just players Thibaut and Fred have a record on the 3 gp ( Samir has just a record on two gp ) ).

I have no idea how I can get that, of course this SQL query is retrieving a sum but from this query I want to escape the guys that don't have a record on every GPs, but I'm blocked at that point ...

```
SELECT p.name, sum(time) 
from records r 
join gp g on r.gp_id = g.id 
join player p on r.player_id = p.id
group by r.player_id
```

Thanks in advance guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use having count to exclude the records that don't have a record on every GPs.

Try:

```
select p.name,
       sum(`time`) as tot_sum
from records r
inner join player p on r.player_id=p.id
inner join gp g on g.id=r.gp_id
group by p.name
having count(distinct gp_id) = (select count(distinct id) from gp)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/t8QwSFDY

`having count(distinct gp_id) = (select count(distinct id) from gp)` will match only the records in the `record` table that have a record on every gp.

Comment: I think the `distinct` in the subquery is unnecessary. Since it's an id, I'd expect/hope that the field is marked as `unique` or `autoincrement`.